# How to get parent url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

For instance my current url is

```
http://www.sample.com/check/?code=1
```

Web page under this url contains a link

```
<a href="http://www.sample.com/check/?code=2">Code2</a>
```

When this link is clicked it takes to  `http://www.sample.com/check/?code=2`

**Question:**
Under the web page displayed under `http://www.sample.com/check/?code=2` i have to fetch the url from which this page had came from. How to do this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(document.referrer);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you control the original page, then you could put a source in the URL like this:

```
<a href="http://www.sample.com/check/?code=2&scr=http://foo.com/xxxx">Code2</a>
```

and you could parse that out of the URL in the 2nd page.

Or you can look at `document.referrer` in the 2nd page and see if it contains the value you want.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.referrer for info about the referrer.

Answer (score 0):

Information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer